# How to show a Kanji stroke order tooltip for each Kanji character being right-clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have installed [KanjiStrokeOrders](https://sites.google.com/site/nihilistorguk/) font on my machine to show the Kanji stroke order.

## Objective

I want to create a web page for my own purpose of learning Japanese. When HTML pages are viewed on the browser, I want to be able to show the stroke order of a single Kanji character being right-clicked via a tooltip with `KanjiStrokeOrders` font family and of course with a bigger font size.

## My Attempt

The following code is my attempt but it just toggles the font whenever I hover the region bounded by the `body`. The result is annoying because,

- the space is dynamically changed so it produces blinking that is not eye-friendly,
- I cannot select just a single character,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function toggleFont() {
            var _font = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily;
            if (_font != 'KanjiStrokeOrders') {
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = 'KanjiStrokeOrders';
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize = '120px';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize = '12pt'; // return to the normal font
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>


<body onmouseover="toggleFont();" onmouseout="toggleFont();">

    僕は合気道が好きだ。I love Aikido.

</body>

</html>
```

## Questions

How to show a tooltip with `KanjiStrokeOrders` font whenever a single character is right-clicked and the tooltips vanishes when the mouse is released?

Comment: why do you want to use Right-click? in web its not good practice to use right-click

Comment: @TawfiqInjass: Any hot keys are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to interact with each letter alone you need to have each letter in its own tag
like this:

```
<span>僕</span><span>は</span><span>合</span><span>気</span>
```

then add the event to each span
you can write a small javascript to put each character in its own span

I suggest putting this on character hover. or on click and hold.

Comment: But tagging for every single Kanji seems to be a nightmare. The HTML code becomes cluttered.

Comment: don't do it manually do it using a javascript check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896591/wrapping-each-character-in-a-span

Comment: its your only solution if you want to interact with each letter alone