# jQuery - How to wrap each character from a string in spans

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the characters of a div into spans?

For example, I'd like to convert this:

```
<div>
    Hello World
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div>
    <span>H</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>W</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>d</span>
</div>
```

I've tried [this StackOverflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896591/wrapping-each-character-in-a-span), but that converts spaces into spans. What I need is to convert only characters to spans:

```
$("div").each(function (index) {
    var characters = $(this).text().split("");

    $this = $(this);
    $this.empty();
    $.each(characters, function (i, el) {
        $this.append("<span>" + el + "</span");
    });
 });
```

Comment: [`$('div').html(function(i, html) {
 return html.replace(/\S/g, '<span>$&</span>');    
});`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tfb90wut/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method with a callback to reduce the code.

```
$("div").html(function(index, html) {
  return html.replace(/\S/g, '<span>$&</span>');
});
```

```js
$("div").html(function(index, html) {
  return html.replace(/\S/g, '<span>$&</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with this simple **JavaScript**.

```js
(function() {
  var div, i, span = "";
  div = document.querySelectorAll("div")[0];
  for (i = 0; i < div.innerText.length; i++) {
    if (div.innerText[i] !== " ") {
      span += "<span>";
      span += div.innerText[i];
      span += "</span>";
    }
  }
  div.innerHTML = span;
}());
```

```html
<div>
  Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use regular expression:

```js
var txt = $('#container').text();
var newTxt = txt.replace(/\w/g,function(c){
  return '<span>'+c+'</span>';
})
$('#container').html(newTxt);
```

```css
span {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#dfdfdf;
  color:#aaa;
  padding:3px;
  margin:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: please i'd like to know what mean of function(c) what is goal of character (c)

Comment: @MoHamedHaSsn `c` here is the string matched by regex i.e. `\w` which means alphanumeric & underscore character.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('h1');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
```

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").each(function (index) {
var characters = $(this).text().split("");

$this = $(this);
$this.empty();
$.each(characters, function (i, el) {
if(el != ' ')
$this.append("<span>" + el + "</span");
});
```

put a condition for space

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("div").each(function (index) {
  var characters = $(this).text().split("");
  characters = characters.filter(v => v != '');
  $(this).empty();
  for(var i =0; i < characters.length; i++) {
      $(this).append("<span>" + characters[i] + "</span");
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tried to write as little as I can

html

```
<div>
    HelloWorld
</div>
```

js

```
var d=$("div");
var text=d.text();
text=$.trim(text);
d.empty();

for(i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    var span=$("<span></span>");
    span.text(text[i]);
    d.append(span)
}
```