# How to wrap each letter in a span and keep normal word breaks and subelements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to wrap each letter inside an HTML element into it's own span (for animation purposes).

This is doable by splitting the text into chars and creating multiple spans (See [jQuery - How to wrap each character from a string in spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115356/jquery-how-to-wrap-each-character-from-a-string-in-spans)).

Only this way word wrapping will not work anymore since words/letters are broken up into spans.
Also child elements (like strong) are removed.

Example:

```js
$.fn.convertToSeperateLetters = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var html = $(this).text().replace(/\S/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>');
    return $(this).html(html)
  });
}

$('p').convertToSeperateLetters();
```

```css
p,
.word,
.letter {
  padding: 3px 1px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.word-wrapped {
  width: 360px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello World</p>
<p>Hello <strong>World</strong></p>

<div class="word-wrapped">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you accept your answer, it can be used for "does this answer your question".  Eg someone is asking how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66389433/jquery-prevent-replace-on-href

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks. Good catch! I answered the question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an solution that also wraps each word into a span. This way wrapping still works on whole words.

Also (1 level) of sub-elements is preserved in the end result. For example:

```
a <strong>bc</strong> d
```

Is converted into:

```
<span class="word">
  <span class="letter">a</span>
</span>
<span class="word">
  <span class="letter">
    <strong>b</strong>
  </span>
  <span class="letter">
    <strong>c</strong>
  </span>
</span>
<span class="word">
  <span class="letter">d</span>
</span>
```

Known issues:

- Only one level of sub-elements works (So `<p>Hello <strong><u>W</u>orld</strong></p>` won't)
- Text against another element create two separate words (So `<p>User<strong>name</strong></p>` are two words)

The full solution:

```js
$.fn.convertToSeperateLetters = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var elements = convertToSeperateLetters($el, false);

    $el.empty().append(elements);

    return $el;
  });
}

$('p').convertToSeperateLetters();

function convertToSeperateLetters($element, asSubNode) {
  var elements = [];

  var childNodes = $element.contents();

  // Loop through all child nodes of selected element
  for (var c = 0; c < childNodes.length; c++) {
    var node = childNodes[c];
    var type = node.nodeType;

    // Process a child element
    if (type == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(elements, convertToSeperateLetters($(node), true));
    }

    // Process a piece of text
    else if (type == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      var text = node.nodeValue;

      // Process each word
      var words = text.split(' ');
      for (var w = 0; w < words.length; w++) {
        var word = words[w];

        // Skip empty words
        if (word == '') continue;

        // Wrap each word into span
        var $word = $('<span/>').addClass('word');
        for (var l = 0; l < word.length; l++) {
          var letter = word[l];

          // Wrap each letter into span
          var $letter = $('<span/>').addClass('letter');

          if (!asSubNode) {
            $letter.html(letter);
          }

          if (asSubNode) {
            var $subNode = $element.clone().empty().html(letter);
            $letter.append($subNode);
          }

          $word.append($letter);
        }

        elements.push($word);
      }
    }
  }
  return elements;
}
```

```css
p,
.word,
.letter {
  padding: 3px 1px;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.word {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.word-wrapped {
  width: 360px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello World</p>
<p>Hello <strong>World</strong></p>

<div class="word-wrapped">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
</div>
```